# Find out where Log come from in smack library?

Tags: xmpp, smack, stream-management

I'm new using smack with openfire as server to make chat app.

I want to make status messages like whatsapp does, if user send a message the icon status message to be sending first,next if achieve server to be single thick, and double thick if it delivered, and so on.
I use that scheme in my app and success except when message achieved by server, i want to change my icon status to single thick, after i send a message i get Log `RECV (0): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='5' />` it Log mean the message has been successfull achieved by the server. i want to know where it Log come from (class that created the log ) so i can trace and change the status message icon to single thick ?

I use Openfire latest version and smack 4.1.5

Answer (score 0):

Use a stanza acknowledged listener, e.g. https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/4.1.6/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/tcp/XMPPTCPConnection.html#addStanzaIdAcknowledgedListener(java.lang.String,%20org.jivesoftware.smack.StanzaListener)